# Firing an onSuccess in an activity with an async HTTP request

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm writing a simple weather app in order to learn how to program for Android however I've come unstuck.

At the moment the app gets the users GPS location, and then sends a request to an API in order to get the weather information. The problem is, I've abstracted these API calls to another class called `Darksky` and they run asynchronously.

This becomes a problem when I do something like: `weeklyForecast = darksky.getWeeklyForecast();`. Because the request runs asynchronously in the `getWeeklyForecast()` method, `weeklyForecast` will come back as empty because the method returned before it got a response from the API.

Here's that method for anyone interested:

```
public ArrayList<Forecast> getWeeklyForecast() {
    // Clear before inserting new data
    weeklyForecast.clear();

    client.get(BASE_URL + API_KEY + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?units=uk&exclude=hourly%2Calerts%2Cflags", null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject daily = root.getJSONObject("daily");
                JSONArray forecasts = daily.getJSONArray("data");

                // Loop through every day
                for (int i = 0; i < forecasts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject dayObject = forecasts.getJSONObject(i);

                    weeklyForecast.add(new Forecast(
                        dayObject.getInt("time"),
                        dayObject.getString("summary"),
                        dayObject.getString("icon"),
                        dayObject.getDouble("temperatureMin"),
                        dayObject.getDouble("temperatureMax"),
                        dayObject.getDouble("windSpeed"),
                        dayObject.getDouble("humidity")
                    ));
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle   
            }
        }
    });

    return weeklyForecast;
}
```

How can I detect when the HTTP request's `onSuccess()` event fires from my main activity?

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface to get the callback once the download is completed as shown below.

```
class Darksky{

    interface updateUI{
        void onFinishedDownload(ArrayList<Forecast> array);
    }

    public ArrayList<Forecast> getWeeklyForecast() {
        // Clear before inserting new data
        weeklyForecast.clear();

        client.get(BASE_URL + API_KEY + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?units=uk&exclude=hourly%2Calerts%2Cflags", null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject daily = root.getJSONObject("daily");
                    JSONArray forecasts = daily.getJSONArray("data");

                    // Loop through every day
                    for (int i = 0; i < forecasts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dayObject = forecasts.getJSONObject(i);

                        weeklyForecast.add(new Forecast(
                                dayObject.getInt("time"),
                                dayObject.getString("summary"),
                                dayObject.getString("icon"),
                                dayObject.getDouble("temperatureMin"),
                                dayObject.getDouble("temperatureMax"),
                                dayObject.getDouble("windSpeed"),
                                dayObject.getDouble("humidity")
                                ));
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle   
                }

                updateUI.onFinishedDownload(weeklyForecast);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

In your Activity or UIClasses you just need to instantiate the updateUI interface and use the arraylist passed :

```
@Override
public void onFinishedDownload(ArrayList<Forecast> array) {
    // Do something with your arraylist here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a listener-  pass the Darksky class an object with a downloadComplete method when you start the download.  Call it in onSuccess, and pass it the results.  Update the UI when downloadComplete is called.